How to change the dir of an existing git project
I have made an Visual Studio project and I made it to be on github. After some time of expansion I realized the config files were getting too big, causing time to download in one of my slower machines and even reached the 100mb limit.
Is there a way I can change the dir of the project into a subfolder, without making a new project? (I want to keep the commit history).

What do you mean by "change the dir of the project into a subfolder" - change where the repository is on your system, or change the structure of the repository?

Yes, you can change the directory structure of your existing Git project without losing commit history.

Create the subfolder:
First, create the new subfolder in your project directory.

sh
mkdir new_subfolder

2. **Move the project files into the subfolder**:
Move all the files and directories (except the `.git` directory) into the new subfolder.

```sh
git mv * new_subfolder/
git mv .* new_subfolder/

Note: The git mv .* new_subfolder/ command might throw warnings for . and .. entries. You can ignore these warnings.

Commit the changes:
After moving the files, commit the changes to your Git repository.
git add .
git commit -m "Moved project files into new_subfolder"


Update your GitHub repository:
Push the changes to your GitHub repository.
git push origin main

Replace main with the name of your branch if you're using a different branch.


Here’s a summary of the commands:
mkdir new_subfolder
git mv * new_subfolder/
git mv .* new_subfolder/
git add .
git commit -m "Moved project files into new_subfolder"
git push origin main

Important considerations:

Ensure that you do not move the .git directory itself, as it contains your repository's version history.
If you have files or directories starting with a dot (e.g., .env), make sure to move them as well.

After these steps, your project files will be inside the new subfolder, and the commit history will be preserved.

I can't commit, because some files in a folder are too large, I deleted the folder and did git rm -cached, but did nothing. Any idea?
